# How to prevent jQuery from reloading on page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm showing hidden textboxes using jQuery like so:

```
      $("#showTextBox").click(function () {
      $("#TextBox").fadeIn("slow");
      });
```

This works fine, but once the page is refreshed, the texbox is hidden again. Is there a way to work around this so that the textbox doesn't hide after a page refresh? Once the textbox is made visible, I don't want it to be hidden again. I'm working with ASP.NET.

Comment: You could store the state of the textbox in a cookie, then on page refresh hide it with asp or javascript based on the cookie value. You could also use any other client-side storage device, such as localstorage.

Comment: How are you hiding the textbox in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can store a variable in localStorage/a cookie and refer to that, e.g.:

```
var $TextBox = $("#TextBox");

if (localStorage.getItem('clicked')) {
     $TextBox.show();
} else {
    $("#showTextBox").click(function () {
        $TextBox.fadeIn("slow");
        localStorage.setItem('clicked', true);
    });
}
```

Just be aware you'll need a polyfill for older browsers if using localStorage:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-storage-localstorage-and-sessionstorage